# Enabling Access Control

Tags: mongodb, shell, access-control

I recently installed mongo db and ran it for the first time. I encountered this warning,

```
 Access control is not enabled for the database.
 Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
```

I fixed this by enabling access control using these commands

```
 db.createUser( 
  { 
    user:"myuserName", 
    pwd:"myPassword", 
    roles:[{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db:"admin"}]
  })
```

From the docs, I have to restart mongodb with this command:

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
```

but when I try to restart mongodb after access control, I get this error.

```
2017-08-17T19:11:14.337+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:9
```

Is the command wrong or am I missing something here. Please walk me through this. Thanks.

Comment: `E QUERY` is telling us that you are actually running that from inside the `mongo` shell instead of on the command line, which is actually where you run the [`mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/) daemon. You really should be setting [configuration file options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) and running `mongod` as a service as is also well documented for your platform.

Comment: @NeilLunn, is there another way to run mongod. Pls explain

Comment: What is your operating system? Windows or Unix based? There is extensive documentation on the install and running process.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: There are extensive instructions on [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) in the core documentation. Particularly the section of [Manually Create a Windows Service for MongoDB Community Edition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition). So it really does help to read all the documentation rather than just "skim it".